# FieldValue isEqual usage

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

In the [Firestore reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#isequal) there is a `firebase.firestore.FieldValue` class that contains mostly static methods, but also has `isEqual` non-static method:

> **isEqual**
>
> `isEqual ( other :  FieldValue ) : boolean`
>
> Returns true if this FieldValue is equal to the provided one.

I’ve puzzled over use-cases when we possibly need this method and I'm still not sure I have any good one.

Has anyone used it successfully and in what circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Java implementation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue

You will see that FieldValue extends Object, which is where FieldValue actually gets its equals implementation from.

This is just a standard method that all objects have. Most OOP languages give all objects an Equals (usually hashcode as well) ToString etc. They are just defaults in the language and have a default implementation equivalent to testing if two references are the same (ie using == operator)

Comment: So this method here is just a rudiment from java implementation where all objects have `isEqual` method - is that what you thinking?

Comment: Very likely yes, as all other objects in the firebase documentation also have the same base methods, including isEqual